# Using ProgressBar for specific time

Tags: c#, winforms

I want my `ProgressBar` starting in some point in my code and run total of seconds until my file finish, and of course I know how long the run of my file will take.
I try to read on MSDN but I did not understood how to use it.

My application run files (wireshark file, send the packet using bittwist) and each file will run few seconds and I want the option to see the progress ongoing.

For example I want to set my `ProgressBar` running for 30 seconds.
How can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: [and of course i know] Why ask then? But ok.. what file? and File's do finish? and File's do run? If you want a decent answer pls post a decent question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
public void AnimateProgBar (int milliSeconds)
{
    if (!timer1.Enabled)  {
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        timer1.Interval = milliSeconds / 100;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (progressBar1.Value < 100) {
        progressBar1.Value += 1;
        progressBar1.Refresh();
    } else {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Then you just have to call `AnimateProgBar(2000)` to have your `ProgressBar` animated during 2 seconds.

EDIT: Sorry, I posted code in VB.NET. Modified to C#.
EDIT: You can add the handler and call the function in this way (for example):

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
        AnimateProgBar(2000);
    }
```

Comment: why my code did not get into timer1_Tick function ?

Comment: `this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);` VisualStudio create that automatically if you double-click on your `Timer` on the Designer View of your project.

Comment: i have this function but under running my code did not get into this function

Comment: I told you, you have to add the handler. I edit my code so you can see how to add it manually.